# Error importing sklearn.utils._logistic_sigmoid modules

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I've installed `scipy` and `scikit-learn` from [Christoph Gohlke Unofficial Windows installers](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs), and the following commands run successfully without error :

```
>>> import sklearn
>>> import scipy
```

Then I was going to try [`sklearn.datasets.load_digits()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_digits.html) function as demonstrated in the linked documentation :

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
```

but that line triggered an error complaining about, as I understand it, `_log_logistic_sigmoid` was not found :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .twenty_newsgroups import fetch_20newsgroups
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\twenty_newsgroups.py", line 53, in <module>
    from ..feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import text
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 29, in <module>
    from ..preprocessing import normalize
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .data import Binarizer
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ..utils.extmath import row_norms
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\extmath.py", line 23, in <module>
    from ._logistic_sigmoid import _log_logistic_sigmoid
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Anybody ever experienced this error? How to fix that?

I'm using python 2.7 on windows 8 machine if that help.

Comment: Install [numpy+mkl](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by uninstalling the unofficial package, then reinstall from the official package using the following command :

```
pip install -U numpy scipy scikit-learn
```